# Firebase Database Read Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read some values from Firebase Real time database. 
My structure looks like this:

[image]

and my code to retrieve the value("Wine and Dine"):

```
databaseReference.child("test").child("event_name").child("drinks")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Object dataSnapshotObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                   if(dataSnapshotObject != null){
                    Toast.makeText(content, "Event Name: " + dataSnapshotObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }else
                    Toast.makeText(context,"null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            });
```

However, I only get a null response as the value. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes I have, but with my reputation I can't mark an answer as a solution :(

Comment: @user8284066 if you found my answer useful, consider marking it as correct by clicking the check button, on the side of the answer, it should turn green. I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may remove `.child("drinks")` from the chain (and put it in later, as in code below)and if you want to make the `dataSnapshotObject` to `String` anyway, then you should retrieve it in a `String`.

Something like this:

```java
String value = dataSnapshot.child("drinks").getValue(String.class);
```

Also check if your `databaseReference` looks something like this or not.

```java
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Comment: I stared at the code for a few minutes, but don't see it. Can you explain why this works, while the original code does not?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think the `databaseReference` was something that was a bit messed up. Otherwise, there's no reason I think I can give, for this working and the other one not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to get the value

Code sample:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("test").child("event_name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            HashMap hashUser = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (hashUser != null) {
                String Drinks = hashUser.get("drinks").toString();
                //Toast.makeText(this, Drinks , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```